# how to pass variables value from dialog form to child form without close the dialog form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dialog

i have (mdi parent form) and (childs form) 
in child form i have datagridview with columns (code,description,qty) which get its data from dialog form properties
how i can pass dialog form properties to child datagridview without closing the dialoge

in child i can use this

```
Private Sub ItemsLookupTile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ItemsLookupTile.Click
    If ItemsLookupForm.ShowDialog(Me) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.ok Then
        Me.Grid.Rows.Add(ItemsLookupForm.code,ItemsLookupForm.description,ItemsLookupForm.qty)
    End If
End Sub
```

but in the above code dialog form closed and the user must click the button again to add another item , i tried to use

```
Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None
```

but it did not work

Comment: what is the exception you are getting? how is it not working?

Comment: thanks for reply i want when user click add button in  dialog form datagridview in child form add dialog form properties without closing

Comment: Edit into your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is have a class representing a row in the datagridview and pass a list of that class to the dialog form in the constructor.  Now the dialog can fill the list before it's closed and the child form can access the list when the dialog is closed.

You could try accessing the datagridview directly but the result will be the same the additions won't show up until the dialog is closed.

Comment: i want when user click add button in dialog form the data inserted directly into child datagridiview row but without close the dialog so user can add another item till he close the dialog

Comment: The problem is the child form is inactive until the dialog is closed.  Saving the additions to a list then adding them as soon as the dialog is closed is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: You could try accessing the datagridview directly but the result will be the same the additions won't show up until the dialog is closed.